# Enable the drag and drop feature for text rearrangement within any text box on any web page

Tags: html, google-chrome, drag-and-drop, webbrowser-control

I'm using Google Chrome and sometimes a website doesn't support "drag & drop" for its text box. I know little about HTML attributes, like those in this link - https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_draggable.asp.
 Is there a way to implement this feature regardless of the website by modifying HTML attributes, programming or other means?

Comment: Did you mean: the browser doesn't support "drag & drop"? There is no reason why a website should don't support code like these.

Comment: @Gismo1337 No, I'd like to enable this feature on a certain website that doesn't  support it. I intend to achieve this through third party tools.